# How to design internal methods access scope?

Tags: java, design-patterns, frameworks

We have a small lightweight framework with around 20 classes, used by 50+ developers and semi-large code base. To keep the framework small, we've avoided creating too many interfaces, abstract classes, etc. This is a trade-off to speed up adaptation by new developers as well as keep code complexity low.

So we do not utilize internal/external interfaces or heavy use of factory classes. We rely on a few classes with public/private methods to define scope. However sometimes methods have to be public but only be accessible to the framework and not the developer.

Example:

```
public class Logger
    public boolean isDebugEnabled() {...}
    public void enableDebug() {...}
```

enableDebug is an "internal" framework method and is documented with "Do not use - Internal class". The method cannot be private nor at package scope due to framework structure.

Once in a while a developer will miss the javadoc and invoke an internal method which can produce unexpected results at runtime.

Example:

```
if (!Logger.isDebugEnabled) {
    Logger.enableDebug(); // screw the javadoc - i'm enabling debug logging
}
```

The framework team is thinking the best approach is to name them following a certain convention. This will not introduce compile-time safety, but decrease error probability.

Example:

```
public void enableDebugInternal() or _enableDebug() or $enableDebug()
```

is more precise than

```
/**
* Internal method - do not use
*/
public void enableDebug()
```

Another option they are thinking is to wrap all internal methods into an internal class:

```
public class Logger
    public boolean isDebugEnabled() {...}
    public class Internal {
        public void enableDebug() {...}
    }
```

Can you recommend a better approach ?
Preferably something that provides compile-time safety

EDIT: Turns out what I am looking for is a design pattern for the keyword "internal" for C# in java:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels

Answer (score 1):

Well, you pretty much answered your own question. You can't change the access level, so you'll pretty much have to change the name of it. A bit hacky, but you could also deprecate the method. Hamcrest does something... err... interesting... with [the Matcher interface](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matcher.html#_dont_implement_Matcher___instead_extend_BaseMatcher_()) to this effect.

If you want to *enforce* that it's not used outside of the package then you'll need to do some kind of static analysis as part of your build. If I had no other choice, I'd write a Maven plugin to look for usages.

Ultimately, it sounds like your design is wrong if you have a public method that needs to act as if it were package-private.

You shouldn't be writing your own logging facade anyway, especially if you're writing a framework. You should be using [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/).

Comment: The issue is not related to logging, it was just an example I used. Secondly, the scope I am looking for is not package-private, it is jar-private. I'll checkout the matcher interface

Comment: @KelvinWayne Use the Java 9 module system then

Comment: That would work, except we're currently stuck on java v8 with no plans to upgrade (for now)